# Odd behaviour with Firefox and body height 100%

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm writing markup and styles for what is a fairly simple and common approach to a body / html 100% height. I've included some simple reset styles, and some basic styles. I have a block level element, absolutely positioned with the assigned `bottom: 0;` property and value.

**Here's what's weird:** When I assign the `font-family` to say `Arial`, it creates a vertical scroll-bar in Firefox (46.0).

I've done this a number of times, not ever noticing or experiencing what *seems to be* like a Firefox bug.

I'm aware that yes, I can:

1. Set the `overflow` property to `hidden`

I've tried and been able to determine the following:

1. Removing the `body {line-height: 1;}` resolves the issue
2. Remove or reset the `font-family` assignment back to `serif`

That said, none of those is a viable option. **This is driving me batty.** Am I missing something?

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* < Reset (end) -------------------------------- */

html {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.footernav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="footernav">
  <p>Hello World! Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the cause of the issue is, but if you're looking for a different solution to your problem then you can use overflow:hidden on your footernav div

```css
.footernav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://codepen.io/lukemeaden/pen/mPzbam

Comment: Yeah, a band-aid fix though. Technically speaking this shouldn't be required though. And in fact, if my design required to position elements relative to that container, this solution would not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Add some vertical padding (e. g. `.2em`) to the text container (`P` element in your example) so that Firefox wouldn’t be forced to show vertical scrollbar just to show text entirely due to that `line-height` value is not enough to fit text contents.

To see the real space needed for the text, select it via `Ctrl+A` and you’ll see that the selection goes beyond the bottom edge of the container if there is no compensating vertical padding.

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPzdjj)

By the way, based on my experience, the optimal default `line-height` is `1.25`; it provides consistency across browsers while fitting entire line without lines overlapping each other in most of cases.

Comment: I could do that, it's not ideal though. Yes, when writing typographic styles, I will override and re-define line height but that's not off subject.